# Is there any way to limit bandwidth usage by process ID in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, performance

Is there any way to basically do traffic shaping based on process ID or name within a Windows instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a great program called NetLimiter 2 Pro:
[www.NetLimiter.com](http://www.netlimiter.com/)

It allows you to specify the exact maximum bandwith for applications AND processes, and it also runs as a service, so once set, you dont need the UI running.

Works fine with XP, Vista and 7 and does the job perfectly
(Infact, it's the only one i've found that works with the BBC iPlayer too!)

and at $30 for the full version after a 30 day trial, it's not much either!

Answer (score 1):

Network bandwidth monitor shall be able to monitor real-time upload/download bandwidth and connections of every computer. So the administrator can diagnose bandwidth usage and network bottleneck. Some network monitoring programs, for example "WFilter Enterprise", can identify the connection protocol type of each connection, so you will be able to know what is running in your network.

Bandwidth monitor program shall also have a detailed bandwidth report.