# IP/process based bandwidth usage stats tool for windows

Tags: windows, ip, bandwidth, process, network-traffic

I wanted to track which process in my windows OS is eating up my bandwidth. I've found similar question [for Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/44492/ip-process-based-bandwidth-usage-stats-tool-for-linux). The tool mentioned in this answer is available for linux only I think. Is there any similar kind of tool for windows?

Answer (score 1):

Refer below question already asked before on ServerFault. That might meet your requirements.

[Is there any way to limit bandwidth usage by process ID in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/51324/is-there-any-way-to-limit-bandwidth-usage-by-process-id-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bwmon, it's written in Python and released under the BSD license (you can use and modify it as you like, even for commercial use).

http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Networking-Tools/bwmon-64358.html

Here are some key features of "bwmon":

· Combination of conntrack+pipe monitors possible
· Open Framework: Create new monitoring methods
· Support for SLA parameter input (bandwidth allocation)
· Support for SLA violation notification to external services
· Fully documented source code and user manual
· Uses ip_conntrack to track connections
· Alternative, cross-platform "pipe" traffic monitor
· Easily customizable: Written in Python

Answer (score 0):

Try using Networx, it's what I use and seems to work fine. You can also set quota.