# Does process priority in task manager affect network traffic?

Tags: windows, networking, task-manager, process-priority

I'm running a database server that's under moderately heavy load. I just kicked off xcopy on that box to copy a database backup to a remote server.

I see that xcopy is using almost all my available bandwidth. I'm worried that it will hog bandwidth that the database would otherwise use.

If I lower xcopy's priority in taskmgr, will that de-prioritize the network traffic, or just CPU time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not prioritize network traffic's bandwdith. You will need a third party tool to perform process-based bandwidth throttling. Check out these Stack Exchange threads to find products that you might benefit from:

- [Windows program to limit bandwidth of other programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/135719/windows-program-to-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs)
- [Is there any way to limit bandwidth usage by process ID in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/51324/is-there-any-way-to-limit-bandwidth-usage-by-process-id-in-windows)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a hundred times!

Answer (score 2):

That affinity is just CPU affinity not network.